# Jmeter: scenario: I have to run 10 Concurrency users for login with one single login data

Tags: authentication, jmeter

[image]

I created concurrency Thread Group with 10 Users in 1 Min, but when i run it ,i am getting 409 conflict in Login Authorization request.

is it possible to run 10 Concurrent Users with single login details?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlYIO.png)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the system under test is configured, in your case it seems to be [impossible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/409)

In general you need to [configure JMeter to behave exactly like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser), to wit each JMeter's thread (virtual user) must represent a real user using a real browser and a real user:

- has its **own credentials**
- [cache](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager)
- [cookies](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)
- [think time](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers)
- [business actions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller)

so ideally you need to create as many "login details" as virtual users you need to simulate